# Subversion and external collaborators: HTTPS vs. VPN

Tags: security, vpn, svn, https

We are currently having some issues with VPN connections. The whole thing slows down development and reaction time. What I was used to in my previous workplace was using SSH for accessing FTP and HTTPS for self-hosted Subversion.

In real world production environments: how often do you use VPN instead of HTTPS for accessing Subversion repositories by external employees? If you do, was security the main concern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We run SSL on our subversion repositories for external access, simply because it's just so much easier than VPNs to:

- Maintain (there is no maintanance)
- Set up (takes about 10 minutes)
- Configure clients (None needed)
- 100% compatibility guaranteed (No funky VPN clients)
- Cross-platform
- Much more secure (No chance of forgetting to set a firewall rule and opening up your entire network)
- No need for SSH (great for Windows clients)

Comment: Subversion is really elegant and user friendly in that you just use an url and everything just works out ... only trouble i ever got into as a user was accidentaly installing TortoiseCVS instead of TortoiseSVN on windows :-)

Answer (score 2):

I use svn+ssh basically everyhwere. For people who don't ever need to run anything but svn on the  server, you can prepend something like this to the front of their `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`:

`command="svnserve -t --tunnel-user=theuser",no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-pty`

This does mean that your users need to use public key auth, but hey that's not a bad thing, right?

Answer (score 2):

Both https and a VPN create an SSL tunnel,  using both is redundant.   Use a VPN if you need to give the collaborators access to other network resources,  like a file share.

At work we use HTTPS with a certificate that costs us $30 per year.  I highly recommend using a CA as it thwarts MITM attacks.